# Debian DomU on Debian Dom0

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, xen

I've set up xen on a Debian squeeze DomU and it seems to be working. I followed the [this guide](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen)

The problem I have is when I try to start the VM and attach the console using

```
xm create -c /etc/xen/myconfig.cfg
```

I see the boot menu, but then after that nothing happens, I get no output. It just remains stuck on the boot menu.

I'm thinking that the problem is that my Dom0 is text only (no X server installed), but the Debian DomU is actually graphical? I've tried looking for a way to install a purely text only DomU but nothing seems to work.

How can I configure this system so that I can attach my DomU to the console and access it properly?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see the config file you're using - it is possible you are correct, that it's trying to boot graphical, but the config file will help.  In the config are parameters for VNC-based console, SDL console, serial console, etc.  Also, you can pass parameters in the config file to the domU that tell it what device to use for the console - they tend to be very distribution-specific.  SuSE, for example, uses the argument "console=hvc0", which tells the guest kernel to use a Xen console for its output.  I'm not familiar enough with Debian to know what it uses, but you might try some of the documentation for Xen and Linux boot parameters and play with the console= options for getting the text output.